# How to setup new host name (IP address) and port number in xubuntu 16.04 to connecct to wifi internet?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, port, hosts, xubuntu

I explain my situation: I downloaded from google play store NetShare app to make my smartphone as WiFi extender, it works with no problems, BUT I need to change the host name (IP address) and port number in my laptop to get it working!! My system is xubuntu 16.04 and there are NO options to do that via GUI!!! Any suggestions how to do that automatically???? I couldn't find so far a solution. thanks. vladi

Comment: Assuming XUbuntu uses the default settings for the WiFi network, when you connect to the WiFi via the extender (smartphone), the laptop should automatically get a new IP address. A port number is not needed (or available) at the IP network level. Each application will have a (different) port number that it uses.

Comment: @jpaugh What means default settings for wifi network?? It is exactly contrarily- the laptop DOESN'T get the new IP automatically and the port number (8282) is obligatory needed! It seems that you don't no this app (NetShare).

Comment: I hadn't used NetShare before today, and did not realize it requires you to use a proxy. Nonetheless, you must connect to the network before the proxy becomes available. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded the NetShare so that I could understand your question. Here's what the app looks like after you start up the hotspot:

[image: NetShare app instructions]

1. Step one is to connect the device (that is, your PC) to the WiFi network (hotspot) created by your phone
2. Step two is to send all network traffic of your PC through the NetShare app on your phone.<sup>1</sup> On Ubuntu here's how you do that:

   1. Navigate to System Settings
   2. Open *Network*
   3. Find the proxy settings, and change the proxy method from *None* to *Manual*<sup>2</sup>
   4. Input the host address and port number under *HTTP proxy*

<sup>1</sup> This is called a *[proxy server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server)*
<sup>2</sup> As soon as you perform step 2.3, you will loose internet access. If you need further help, change the proxy method back to *None* before trying to use the internet.